# Copy attributes from features in one layer in QGIS to another layer

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, copy

I am building lake bottom topology maps for Lowrance HDS depth finders. Each iteration of map building (addition of new data) generates a new .shp file. To utilize the Lowrance tool that merges .shp files to a map (.at5 file), the features must have certain attributes defined and a value placed in the attribute.

Question is, once I have a .shp file with the attribute fields on the features, and a new .shp file is generated, how can I easily add the attributes to the new .shp features? Is there a way to copy/paste attributes? Or must I re-add each attribute to the new .shp file?

I have seen the postings about saving a feature in the old file and merging it with the new file, but it seems like there should be a simpler way.

Perhaps not. I have not been able to find a way.

Comment: Is there a common field between the two shapefiles that could be used to match the features?

Comment: There might be, and might not. It's a dynamic map. The total map consists of 3-18 .shp files. So, adding the 5 attributes to each .shp file can be tedious. I was just hoping there was an easier way. I suppose I could put in some kind of point with an icon in each .shp file that would be common. But then I would be adding a feature to 18 files each iteration.